# How do I add data from a file to a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io, jtable

Here is my method so far:

```
public void readfile(JTable table) {
        try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("out.txt"));     
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
                table.setValueAt(in.readLine(), i, j);
            }
        }
        in.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

Here are the contents of out.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

Where I run the program and attempt to load the file to the table, nothing happens. I also get an output that says the following:

```
error: 0 >= 0
```

Help me please?

Comment: You need a mutable table model. The [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) has the ability to add rows, but you'll need to configure the columns as well

Comment: Oh man, I've been working with the DefaultTableModel this whole time. Do I have to change everything now?

Comment: `Oh man, I've been working with the DefaultTableModel this whole time` - for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded FileIO as local variable

Comment: *I also get an output that says the following:* that is thanks to your error handling. If you really want to catch all exceptions, at least print the stacktrace as well

Comment: @GigaTocka if the row exists and you want to change the existing value, the setValeAt is what you want. If you want to add new rows, then you need to use one of the addRow methods from the DefaultTableModel (if that's what you're using)

Answer (score 0):

I would narrow your problem down to a smaller problem, solve this smaller problem, and then widen it until you have want you want.

1. Think of the contents of a File as a big blob of text.
2. Think of the table as a Vector of Vectors.

Smaller problem: *How do I convert a big blob of text into a Vector of Vectors?*  You need to be able to sove this problem first before tackling File I/O or DefaultTableModels.